# Google HeaderGridView issue

Tags: android, gridview, header

I use [HeaderGridView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Gallery2/+/idea133/src/com/android/photos/views/HeaderGridView.java) from Google to add header to GridView

But it displays the header incorrectly. Left position of the header is -160. And it makes a distance is 160 from the right side. (I think 160 is a half of item width)

[image]

Here is my code:

```
View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_header, viewGroup, false);
imgBanner = (ImageView) header.findViewById(R.id.img_banner);
gridView.addHeaderView(header);
```

Layout header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/img_cate_banner"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />
```

Layout view

```
<HeaderGridView
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:horizontalSpacing="8dp"
        android:numColumns="2"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:verticalSpacing="8dp" />
```

What did I do wrong? Or it is a bug of HeaderGridView?

Answer (score 2):

It is because `gravity` is set to `center`, if you set it to `left` you will see the whole header content. I think it is a bug, because then the columns will be aligned left.

Comment: Worked for me! any idea how to center the elements from de Grid?